# Errors whenever I access a property

Tags: objective-c, properties

I have a class `JWGeoGame` with these properties:

```
@interface JWGeoGame : NSObject{
    JWCountry *hidden,*last,*prev;
}
@property (nonatomic) JWCountry *hidden;
@property (nonatomic) JWCountry *last;
@property (nonatomic) JWCountry *prev;

//some methods

@end
```

Whenever I try to set any of them, however, I get a cryptic error:

```
Implicit conversion of Objective-C pointer type 'Class' to C pointer type 'struct objc_class *' requires a bridged cast.
```

This error occurs in ech of the following scenarios:

```
self.prev=self.last;
self.prev=nil;
```

When I try to use them for comparisons:

```
if (guess == self.hidden)
    return FOUND;
```

I get another error:

```
Member reference type 'struct objc_class *' is a pointer, did you mean ->?
```

but I get this error when I try -> instead:

```
Member reference base type 'Class' is not a structure of union.
```

Clearly, I'm doing something wrong here, but I can't figure out what, no matter how many examples I look at. How can I fix this?

EDIT:

JWCountry is currently just a skeleton:

```
@interface JWCountry : NSObject{
    NSInteger index;
}
@property NSInteger index;
@end
```

Comment: Can we see JWCountry @interface declaration?

Comment: @JakobWeisblat: And where are the properties declared?

Comment: @MartinR in `JWGeoGame.h` - I added a more complete excerpt above.

Comment: Quite strange, would need the whole project at hand to see what's the problem

Comment: Assuming you're using a relatively recent version of Xcode, remove the instance variable declarations.

Comment: Are you using ARC? Do you synthesize the properties or are they being auto-synthesized? Are you aware that the default storage specifier under ARC is `assign`?

Comment: I got some very similar errors when trying to access properties on `self` from within a class method - are you doing that?

Comment: @CarlVeazey I hadn't used Objective C in a while and thought +/- was public/private. That is the problem I'm sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're possibly using dot syntax to get at properties from a class method, but `self` inside a class method is the actual class object itself, not an instance of the class, and hence doesn't have those properties.

To fix it, make sure that you only access properties of `self` in instance methods. If you need something like class level storage, use static variables.